# How can I create Open vSwitch QoS settings with Ansible?

Tags: ansible, openvswitch

I'm trying to create Open vSwitch QoS settings by using the [Ansible openvswitch_db module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/openvswitch/openvswitch/openvswitch_db_module.html).

The Ansible task should emulate a command like the following:

`ovs-vsctl set port vm00-eth1 qos=@newqos -- --id=@newqos create qos type=egress-policer other-config:cir=30000000 other-config:cbs=3000000`

I tried an Ansible task like the following, but it doesn't change any QoS settings.

```
- openvswitch.openvswitch.openvswitch_db:
    table: Port
    record: vm00-eth1
    col: other_config
    key: cir
    value: 30000000
```

The Ansible task runs through successfully, but there is still no QoS setting on that port:

```
root@host00 ~ # ovs-appctl qos/show vm00-eth1
QoS not configured on vm00-eth1
```